# Adding a view controller to my view and programing freezing. objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a menu at the top with a few buttons and when one selects a differnt button the view much switch to a different view controller. Can be either with a xib file or I can program the interface myself.

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:ViewController bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview:ViewController.view];
```

With an exception breakpoint the program pauses on the first line and then when I continue running it it freezes and doesn't give an error message in the console.

Comment: It would be a good idea not to use capital first letter for your instance objects. ViewController *viewController = .... is the convention of objective-C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing quotes around your nibName:

```
ViewController *ViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Oops my mistake. I have added it but it still giving me the same problem. Can one add a ViewController to a view?

Comment: Yes, you can add a view controllers view as a subview of another view. There really should be an error in the console to aid in debugging if the app is crashing.